# Socket.io socket receives type error and data parser error

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io

I have a Python file which talks to a JavaScript file via socket.io and socket.io-client. The debugger output on the server side is shown below.

Debugger output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL1p7.png

I've tried implementing some fixes recommended in similar posts, for example I changed

```
const socket = io(SOCKETIO_URL)
```

to

```
var options = {};
options.transports = ['websocket'];
const socket = io(SOCKETIO_URL, options , {transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});
```

but that just yields this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcUEX.png.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image

Comment: error shows problem with parsing data - and it can means you send data in wrong way. I wander why you have `?0` before `{"sid":...}` and `?40` after `{"sid":...}` - it seems like wrong chars in JSON data. Where is your code which sends data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into a similar issue and turned out it was caused by version mismatch between socket-io client and socket-io server packages. So make sure you're using similar versions socket io on your server and client.